# Auto-generate Android Log TAG in Android Studio/Intellij idea

Tags: java, android, android-studio, intellij-idea, live-templates

In Intellij Idea when i typing **`psfs`** and then press <kbd>Ctrl+J</kbd> IDE was getting me a dialog :

[image]

And when i press <kbd>Enter</kbd> i get an

[image]

I know where i can customize my own output

[image]

But i can't any doc's how i can write my own live template.

In the end i want to get next result :

#### Typing : `psfst` -> press <kbd>Ctrl+J</kbd> -> press <kbd>Enter</kbd>

#### Result :

`public static final String TAG = <currentClassName>.class.getSimpleName();`

It will be so helpfull, because i have a habit to log my classes.

Answer (score 51, accepted):

I find a solution

**1)** Create a new live template in plain group
**2)** In template text :

```
private static final String TAG = $CLASS_NAME$.class.getSimpleName();
```

**3)** Define a usage scope :

[image]

**4)** Choose a shortcut :

[image]

finally click on <kbd>Edit variables</kbd> and change expression value to className()

[image]

Click <kbd>Ok</kbd> , <kbd>Apply</kbd>, <kbd>Ok</kbd> and use.

Comment: Great tip. As a suggestion, you can use private instead of public, since you set a tag for each class.

Comment: I've modified the default template of `logt` by the one proposed in this solution. It's really what I wanted and the way that It should be implemented. Thanks!

Comment: @SergeyShustikov What about Kotlin?

Comment: This should come included with Android Studio

Answer (score 41):

There already exists such shortcut in Android Studio - write logt and enter while cursor is at the class scope.

more here :

[image: for more see here]

Comment: Not exactly. It will generated template as `private static final String TAG = "<class_name>";` not requested. But I will plus, because however it good 0,02$ to this.

Answer (score 17):

It's super simple in Android studio, just type `logt` and press <kbd>Tab</kbd>.

It generates: `private static final String TAG = "xyzActivity";`

Answer (score 11):

For those using **Android Studio 3** and **Kotlin** it is necessary to change how *Live Templates* set:

Editor >> Live Templates >> AndroidLog

**By default it is just for Java**

[image]

Add Kotlin pressing "change" button and check Kotlin

[image]

and after that it will work again!

[image]

---

**Updated:** 2020

**Android Studio:** 3.6.2

[image]

**Steps:**

1. Add
2. Call logtk are whatever you want to call
3. Use this code as template text

```kotlin
private val TAG = this::class.java.simpleName
```

4. Add a description
5. Do it applicable to Kotlin: in my case I used just for Class

**Update June 2020**

There's no need to set anything up anymore. Android Studio 4.0 comes with this functionality by default. The same with Toast

[image]

Comment: `this` is evaluated for each instance. But the class name is static. Therefor it might be better to put the Log TAG into the companion object.

Answer (score 1):

Another solution is not use a default TAG for each class and use this method to get the TAG:

```
public class Utils {
        public static String getTAG(Object o) {
            StackTraceElement[] elements = Thread.currentThread().getStackTrace();

            int position = 0;
            for (int i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
                if (elements[i].getFileName().contains(o.getClass().getSimpleName())
                        && !elements[i+1].getFileName().contains(o.getClass().getSimpleName())){
                    position = i;
                    break;
                }
            }

            StackTraceElement element = elements[position];
            String className = element.getFileName().replace(".java", "");
            return "[" + className + "](" + element.getMethodName() + ":" + element.getLineNumber() + ")";
        }
}
```

Example call from MainActivity - onResume:

```
Log.v(Utils.getTAG(this), "hello world");
```

Log output:

```
[MainActivity](onResume:79): hello world
```

Comment: Actually is not an answer about auto-generate TAG.

Answer (score 0):

For Kotlin create a live template with
`private val TAG = $CLASS_NAME$::class.java.simpleName` as the template text and in set expression for CLASS_NAME as kotlinClassName() in edit variables.